# "This question has been closed <no description here> by ..."

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, meta

Ok, poking fun at the [worst question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35506/time-for-an-experience-reset-closed) I noticed that it does not have a close reason. How is this? Is this a diamond moderator only thing?

Comment: Also as an added aside: anyone else notice this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=692&sort=votes  Evan Caroll has **TWO** questions on the most downvoted questions page.

Comment: @Earlz: if you have it set to show 50 questions per page, he has four there.

Comment: @George it's getting worse D:

Comment: I think it is an obvious demonstration of GMs being opinionated and biased. This is one of the reasons I often feel obligated to promote banning them for obstructing the network.

Comment: By the way, I previously also proposed this idea http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37482 which would have permitted you to notify me when you want to talk about one of my questions; but, because they closed that one too (without a reason might I add) before a good solution could be reached I can't hold you to blame.

Comment: @Justin did you really just edit the tags so that it bumped the question or something?

Comment: @Earlz I was just looking at tags that only existed in one place.  So, I removed the `[worst-question-ever]` tag.

Comment: @Justin that tag exists on a few deleted questions by Evan :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are questions closed with close reasons that no longer exist. It could have been closed as *Not a real question*, *Subjective and argumentative*, or a few others that I don't recall, but somebody else surely does.

Comment: Right, so the reasons went away because it sucked -- good. Open the question again. I wait anxiously for my other wrongly closed questions to become open.

Comment: @Evan: what makes you think that they were wrongly closed?

Comment: Because I'm guilty until proven innocent. What rule did I break? Why is my question closed? Is being unpopular grounds for closing? Who decided? Is there a subjective or quantifiable grounds for it being closed? Does it apply to others? Take this scenario, "Joe went to prison. Joe is in prison. Joe was never told why he is in prison, even though Joe wants to know the reason." This is categorically wrong for any system of government except for the totalitarian brew of crap we have here on SO.

Comment: last i checked SOFU wasn't a sovereign territory.  was there some war for independence i missed?

Comment: The comments say it was closed because it was "blatantly offensive" (and it was).

Comment: Oh, *blatantly offensive*. How could I forget about thy!

Comment: @json: thee, forget about thee.  Thy = Your, Thee = You.  (Thine = Yours but that's a different episode)

Comment: @Evan Carroll: Joe is in prison because 5 different people wanted Joe in, and he couldn't get 5 people who wanted to get him out. The community has spoken, your 'question' was closed.

Comment: @squillman: [Area 51: English Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1269/english-language-usage)